# Uncaught TypeError: matchExpr[type].exec is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeerror

After modified Object.prototype, all of jQuery's methods running on selectors started resulting in the below error:

`Uncaught TypeError: matchExpr[type].exec is not a function`

And also when I call `$.post()`. it says that `$.post() is not undifined`.

What I did was:

```
Object.prototype.extend = function(object) {
      ...
   }
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Why did you attempt to modify the core methods? You see what mess it would be with this attempt? Never do that!

Comment: I really wonder what would make you overriding `extend` 

Comment: I took an existing project and the previous dev did that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Rule #1: Avoid Monkey Patching at all costs!**

**Overriding methods of built-in Objects** (via the prototype property, as in your example) is a major anti-pattern and it's **considered a really, really bad practice**!

You just need to think of another way to accomplish what you are trying to achieve, without overriding these methods.

You might want to take a look at jQuery's [extend method](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) for example.

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain#Bad_practice_Extension_of_native_prototypes)

[Why is extending native objects a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice)